# How to detect letters and theirs upper/lower case format from two characters which need to be compared to each other?

Tags: javascript, regex, case-sensitive, letter, unicode-escapes

I need to get:

- If either of the characters is not a letter, return -1
- If both characters are the same case, return 1
- If both characters are letters, but not the same case, return 0

Examples:

'a' and 'g' returns 1

'A' and 'C' returns 1

'b' and 'G' returns 0

'B' and 'g' returns 0

'0' and '?' returns -1

Now my code is uncorrect:

```js
function sameCase(a, b) {

  if (a.match(/a-z/) && b.match(/a-z/)) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.match(/A-Z/) && b.match(/A-Z/)) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (b.match(/a-z/) && a.match(/A-Z/)) {
    return 0;
  }

  return -1;
}

console.log(sameCase('a', 'b'));
console.log(sameCase('A', 'B'));
console.log(sameCase('a', 'B'));
console.log(sameCase('B', 'g'));
console.log(sameCase('0', '?'));
```

Help, please..

Comment: Look at what `charAt` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using regex incorrectly. You should have used `/[a-z]/` if you want to check that your character is a letter from a to z.

```js
function sameCase(a, b){
  if (a.match(/[a-z]/) && b.match(/[a-z]/)) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.match(/[A-Z]/) && b.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (b.match(/[a-z]/) && a.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (a.match(/[a-z]/) && b.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return -1;
}
console.log(sameCase('a', 'b'));
console.log(sameCase('A', 'B'));
console.log(sameCase('a', 'B'));
console.log(sameCase('B', 'g'));
console.log(sameCase('0', '?'));
```

Comment: This logic is correct

Comment: yes, i forgot brackets []

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong syntax for the regular expressions.

`/a-z/` matches the string `a-z`. If you want to test for a range of characters, you need to wrap the range in `[]`.

Also your return values didn't match the expectations you described.

```js
function sameCase(a, b) {

  if (
    (a.match(/[a-z]/) && b.match(/[a-z]/)) ||
    (a.match(/[A-Z]/) && b.match(/[A-Z]/))
  ) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (
    (b.match(/[a-z]/) && a.match(/[A-Z]/)) ||
    (b.match(/[A-Z]/) && a.match(/[a-z]/))  
  ) {
    return 0;
  }

  return -1;
}

console.log(sameCase('a', 'b'));
console.log(sameCase('A', 'B'));
console.log(sameCase('a', 'B'));
console.log(sameCase('B', 'g'));
console.log(sameCase('0', '?'));
```

Comment: This logic is incorrect.

Comment: Fixed it. I assumed at least the return values to be correct, which they weren't.

Answer (score 1):

*+++ Just as additional information +++*

Building on top of ***connexo***'s approach and turning it into a solution which does not just cover the basic latin upper- and lower-case letters, one could replace each character class with its [unicode property escapes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) counterpart which in addition covers each a much wider range of characters ...

```js
// based on basic latin letter character classes.
function sameCaseBasicLatin(a, b) {
  if (
    (a.match(/[a-z]/) && b.match(/[a-z]/)) ||
    (a.match(/[A-Z]/) && b.match(/[A-Z]/))
  ) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (
    (b.match(/[a-z]/) && a.match(/[A-Z]/)) ||
    (b.match(/[A-Z]/) && a.match(/[a-z]/))  
  ) {
    return 0;
  }
  return -1;
}

// ... ok ...
console.log('`sameCaseBasicLatin` invoked with basic latin letters');

console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('a', 'b'));
console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('A', 'B'));
console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('a', 'B'));
console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('B', 'g'));
console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('0', '?'));

// ... but ... not ok.
console.log('`sameCaseBasicLatin` invoked with diacritic latin letters');

console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('â', 'ê'));
console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('Â', 'Ê'));
console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('â', 'Î'));
console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('Ô', 'ä'));
console.log(sameCaseBasicLatin('-', '#'));


// make use of unicode property escapes.
function sameCaseLetters(a, b) {

  // lowercase letter as unicode property escape.
  const regXLowerCaseLetter = (/\p{Ll}/u);
  // uppercase letter as unicode property escape.
  const regXUpperCaseLetter = (/\p{Lu}/u);

  if (
    (regXLowerCaseLetter.test(a) && regXLowerCaseLetter.test(b)) ||
    (regXUpperCaseLetter.test(a) && regXUpperCaseLetter.test(b))
  ) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (
    (regXLowerCaseLetter.test(a) && regXUpperCaseLetter.test(b)) ||
    (regXUpperCaseLetter.test(a) && regXLowerCaseLetter.test(b))  
  ) {
    return 0;
  }
  return -1;
}

// ... ok ...
console.log('`sameCaseLetters` invoked with basic latin letters');

console.log(sameCaseLetters('a', 'b'));
console.log(sameCaseLetters('A', 'B'));
console.log(sameCaseLetters('a', 'B'));
console.log(sameCaseLetters('B', 'g'));
console.log(sameCaseLetters('0', '?'));

// ... and ... also ok.
console.log('`sameCaseLetters` invoked with diacritic latin letters');

console.log(sameCaseLetters('â', 'ê'));
console.log(sameCaseLetters('Â', 'Ê'));
console.log(sameCaseLetters('â', 'Î'));
console.log(sameCaseLetters('Ô', 'ä'));
console.log(sameCaseLetters('-', '#'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper methods to determin lower, upper cases
const isLower = x => x === x.toLowerCase();
const isUpper = x => x === x.toUpperCase();

const sameCase = (a, b) => {

  // if either "a" or "b" are not "letter"s, return -1
  if (!a.match(/[a-z|A-Z]/) || !b.match(/[a-z|A-Z]/)) return -1;

  // if both "a" and "b" are either lower or upper case, return 1
  if ((isLower(a) && isLower(b)) || (isUpper(a) && isUpper(b))) return 1;
  
  // return 0 (since "a", "b" are letters, but not same case)
  return 0;
};

console.log("sameCase('a', 'b'): ", sameCase('a', 'b'));
console.log("sameCase('A', 'B'): ", sameCase('A', 'B'));
console.log("sameCase('a', 'B'): ", sameCase('a', 'B'));
console.log("sameCase('B', 'g'): ", sameCase('B', 'g'));
console.log("sameCase('0', '?'): ", sameCase('0', '?'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that is a bit terser:

```js
function sameCase(a, b) {
    const both = a + b;
    if (/[^a-z]/i.test(both)) return -1;
    if (/^(?:[a-z]{2}|[A-Z]{2})$/.test(both)) return 1;
    return 0;
}

function test(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b, sameCase(a,b));
}

test("A", "B");
test("a", "b");
test("A", "b");
test("a", "B");
test("?", "b");
test("a", "?");
test("?", "?");
```